# mod_xml_curl Received HTTP error 404 trying to fetch url

Tags: freeswitch

This is my mod_xml_curl:

```
<configuration name="xml_curl.conf" description="cURL XML Gateway">
  <bindings>
<binding name="directory">
      <param name="gateway-url" value="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/gregory/4d4940f807f830aa1de6/raw/9064dd07b2c8b26bf6bed55861acb021a4c11147/directory.xml" bindings="directory" method='GET'/>
</bindings>
</configuration>
```

This is the issue:

```
>list_users
...
2014-08-23 22:40:41.347953 [ERR] mod_xml_curl.c:315 Received HTTP error 404 trying to fetch https://gist.githubusercontent.com/gregory/4d4940f807f830aa1de6/raw/9064dd07b2c8b26bf6bed55861acb021a4c11147/directory.xml
data: [hostname=c97190edef3c&section=directory&tag_name=&key_name=&key_value=]
```

I made some debug and turns out that the request that is sent is a POST instead of a GET. 
This might be the bug?

Comment: my bad, it should have been actually: <binding name="directory">
      <param name="gateway-url" value="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/gregory/4d4940f807f830aa1de6/raw/9064dd07b2c8b26bf6bed55861acb021a4c11147/directory.xml" bindings="directory"/><param name='method' value='GET' />
</bindings>

Answer (score 2):

I tested - a POST to that URL won't work, it returns a 404.

Perhaps this line: `<param name='method' value='GET' />`

Needs to be: `<param name="method" value="GET" />`

Also: If you're not using POST to send any information, then maybe you just want to use wget, see: http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Mod_xml_curl#Alternative_ways_of_storing_static_configurations

Comment: As i said above, i miss read the doc. This works: <binding name="directory">
 <param name="gateway-url" value="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/gregory/4d4940f807f830aa1de6/raw/9064dd07b2c8b26bf6bed55861acb021a4c11147/directory.xml" bindings="directory"/><param name='method' value='GET' />
</bindings>